# Angular give blank white screen when I import a sdk

Tags: angular, sdk

I want to use `@eth-optimism/sdk` in my angular project. But when I import sdk with `import * as optimismSDK from "@eth-optimism/sdk"` and try to call its functions such as `CrossChainMessenger` angular gives me a white blank screen without any console errors.

In my send component:

```
import * as optimism from "@eth-optimism/sdk";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-send',
    templateUrl: './send.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./send.component.css'],
})

export class SendComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(){}

async send() {

    const signer = await getEthersSigner({
        chainId: 5,
    })

    let crossChainMessenger = new sdk.CrossChainMessenger(
        {
            l1ChainId: 5,
            l2ChainId: 420,
            l1SignerOrProvider: signer,
            l2SignerOrProvider: new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
                "https://goerli.optimism.io"
            ),
        }
    );

}
```

I shortened my code but when I use  `new sdk.CrossChainMessenger` my app crashes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { CrossChainMessenger } from "@eth-optimism/sdk";
```

Comment: nope its not working